# cannot find follow_joint_trajectory topic in ur_robot_driver package

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.

I have been stuck on that a few days, that's why, maybe even being a simple question, I decided to ask.

right now i have been running a UR10 with a personal project using the already deprecated ur_modern_driver package.

I found that, even being a great package, after calling a follow_joint_trajectory order ( in ur_ros_wrapper.cpp) there was no post-checks and automatically a setSucceeded call was sended(https://github.com/ros-industrial/ur_modern_driver/blob/master/src/ur_ros_wrapper.cpp#L230 ).
Due to the needs of my project, i wanted to solve that, but I decided to directly switch to the new and official ros driver for UR ([ur_robot_driver](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/tree/master/ur_robot_driver)) I tough it was a good idea also thinking in a future buy of a e-series robot.

The problem is that i would like to check how actually works the follow_joint_trajectory implementation but I am unable to find it. I am starting to think that, even the packagle clearly says it's compatible, the implementation is inside a dependency of the system.  If i do not find it, I am gonna work on checking using rostopic info command, but the robot have been (and will be, for a while) busy with production.

Thanks for any clue on that!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354912/cannot-find-follow_joint_trajectory-topic-in-ur_robot_driver-package/) by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on ROS Answers with karma: 187 on 2020-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> The problem is that i would like to check how actually works the follow_joint_trajectory implementation but I am unable to find it. I am starting to think that, even the packagle clearly says it's compatible, the implementation is inside a dependency of the system.

`ur_robot_driver` is a [ros_control](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control) compatible [hardware_interface](http://wiki.ros.org/hardware_interface).

This means the driver itself only implements the functionality needed to convert "ROS commands" to whatever the underlying hardware understands (in this case: the CB3 or e-Series controller).

With that in place, we can now use any of the available `ros_control` controllers, provided by [ros_controllers](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_controllers), including the [joint_trajectory_controller](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_trajectory_controller).

None of that code is included in `ur_robot_driver`, simply because it's not needed (and would be unwise to duplicate).

If you're interested to learn how the `JointTrajectoryController` works, you would have to take a look at the files in [ros-controls/ros_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/tree/1fd8d25707e289700743925c93644b4295b1c486/joint_trajectory_controller).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on 2020-06-15**:
Thank you very much @gvdhoorn! Your upvote, sir!